# TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands

Tags: sourcecode, ide, texstudio

I'm starting to use TeXStudio. I'm having some issues, for example with

```
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{a}^2-\sqrt[n]{ab}&=m\sqrt[n]{a}\\
\end{align*}
```

When i put the point on `align*` i get a small message unrecognized command, when it is in `\sqrt` or `^` i get the message math command outside math env, and something similar happens with `&` when it gives me the message tabular command outside tabular env. These commands are highlighted with an orange background.
I have similar mistakes with `\eqref`,`\implies`. Some commands as `\title`,`\author` or `\sqrt`(when it is between dollar signs) don't present any problem.

When i build the PDF, i have no problems at all and it gives me the desired result.
I'd like that TeXStudio recognize these commands

Comment: Is this still reproducible with a recent version of TS? I think this has been fixed. Please confirm!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'm sorry, I don't use TS anymore.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TeXStudio recognises commands that it finds in files ending with `.cwl`. The `\eqref` command and the `align*` environment come from the `amsmath package`, so you need to make sure that `amsmath.cwl` is loaded. Under some circumstances, this will happen automatically, but the mechanism isn't foolproof (e.g. it doesn't know that `amsmath` can be loaded indirectly via `\usepackage{mathtools}`).

On a Mac, you can ensure that `amsmath.cwl` is loaded by going to

```
TeXStudio --> Preferences
```

selecting `Completion` on the left and checking the box next to `amsmath.cwl`. Presumably the procedure is similar on other operating systems. If the other unrecognised commands also come from packages for which TeXStudio has `cwl` files, activate these as well. Section 1.4 of the TeXStudio manual explains how to add your own `cwl` file for commands that do not come from standard packages.

Comment: Same can be done on Win7(x64)

Comment: I have activated the same, but it does not seemed to work. Most of the math symbols like \alpha,^,_ are highlighted. When I build the pdf I don't have a problem

Comment: This fix worked for me yesterday in TeXstudio 2.6.6 but isn't working today. The computer was shut down overnight. For example, `\euro{}` produces the proper output (`€`) but is considered an "unrecognized command", even though I have the eurosym.cwl selected as a completion file.

Comment: @Cerran do `gedit ~/.config/texstudio/eurosym.cwl` and add `\EUR{amount}
\euro
\geneuro#*
\geneuronarrow#*
\geneurowide#*
\officialeuro#*
\eurobars#*
\eurobarsnarrow#*
\eurobarswide#*` (one command per line)

Answer (score 1):

See also [FAQ: How does TeXstudio know about valid commands](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands)

Answer (score 0):

When I was adding superscripts to one of my research articles, I ran into a similar problem. The easiest way I found was to wrap the text with $, which activates inline math mode.

Example:

```
 $ 1^{2} $
```

Result:

1<sup>2</sup>

I hope this information can help.

Answer (score 0):

Instalei o TeXstudio e dei a opção de novo.
Ao tentear digitar o primeira linha de codigo recebo o erro...

unknown at 893035 (TXS-Version 4.3.1 R )
[bt] 000000000064dd70  ??? error: 487

Comment: This is not answer. And please write in English.