# Minor issue with elsarticle and keywords

Tags: elsarticle

I have downloaded the elsarticle template (Previously installing the package), and just opening and executing the raw template (As downloaded from El Sevier, without editing) I have two commands shaded in red: "\ead" and "begin{keyword}". It says "Unrecognized command" and "Unrecognized environment" respectively.

However, when executing the code, I get no errors. **Why is this happening?**

I'm supposed to ignore this errors, because my code is executing normally, but these errors make me to suspect that Im doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}

\author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{Elsevier Inc}
\ead[url]{www.elsevier.com}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which front-end editing program do you employ?

Comment: Hi Mico! Thank you, Im using TeXstudio

Comment: The issue you describe does not appear to be due to a compilation error. Instead, it looks like TeXstudio colors two environment and the macro simply because they haven't been entered into the program's database of known commands and environments. I don't use TeXstudio myself, but I believe that it's straightforward to augment its database of known command names and environment names.

Comment: I think that it is a bug of TeXstudio or something like that. Look at this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47741/problems-with-environments-in-texstudio