# TeXStudio does not recognize \colon

Tags: texstudio

What is the file to load the command `\colon` to be recognized (*as a known command*) by TeXStudio? If I add it to the personal command it works but I guess that this command comes from some package.

ps: I'm talking about highlighting unknown commands.

ps2: I tried `grep colon *.cwl` on my `.config/texstudio` folder and I found

```
mathabx.cwl:\coloneq#Sm
mathabx.cwl:\eqcolon#Sm
mathtools.cwl:\vcentcolon#S
mathtools.cwl:\ordinarycolon#S
mathtools.cwl:\MT_activate_colon#S
mathtools.cwl:\MT_active_colon_true#S
```

that is, no `\colon` command.

Comment: I don't think you need any packages. Are you using this in math mode?

Comment: @PeterGrill, sorry. Probably I'm confusing you guys. My question is about unknown commands by the editor not by LaTeX. Everything is fine with the compilation.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps this is a duplicate of [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-some-commands).

Comment: I found that topic, but it does not consider the command `\colon`. I am not able to find this command.

Comment: You could just add `\colon#S` to a custom `.cwl` file. (It is defined in `plain.tex`: `\mathchardef\colon="603A % colon as a punctuation mark` and is redefined by `amsmath`.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, what is the meaning of `#S` or `#Sm`, on my post? Thanks.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\colon` is defined in `plain.tex` as a punctuation mark (`:` is a relation symbol in math mode)

```
\mathchardef\colon="603A
```

and redefined by `amsmath`.

Unfortunately, TeXstudio doesn’t recognize the command even if the `amsmath.cwl` completion file is selected.

But we can create our own `.cwl` file. On Windows, custom `.cwl` files are stored and recognized by TeXstudio in `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user`. In Linux in `~/.config/texstudio/completion/user`. (more information in [4.13.4 cwl file placement](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION))

Create your own `.cwl` file, I named it `custom.cwl`. One line suffices:

```
\colon#m
```

**Notes:**

- `m` declares it as a math mode command, the use of `\colon` in text mode will still give you the unrecognized highlighting.
- `S`, as I understand it, gives you recognizing (i.e. correct highlighting) but not completion.

After saving the file `custom.cwl` start TeXstudio go to the “Options” menu and open the “Configure TeXstudio” dialog. In the “Completion” tab select `custom.cwl` and apply your changes (“OK”).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a:b$\par
$a{:}b$ \par
$a\mathrel{:}b$ \par
$a{:\,}b$ \par% \colon
$a\colon b$ \par
a \colon b
\end{document}
```

### Screenshots

[image: auto-completion]
[image: \colon is highlightet correct]

Comment: Reference: [TeXstudio user manual, 4.13 “Description of the cwl format”](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION)

Comment: How do you create a .cwl file though? I tried creating in in TXS and one in with a text editor and neither worked when I dragged it into ~/.config/texstudio (for Mac).

Comment: Have you activated the `.cwl` file in the Options menu/Completion tab (see last paragraph of Notes section of this answer)?

Comment: All I see under Options is "Load Profile", "Save Profile", "Save Current Settings", "Define Current Document as Master Document", and "Automatically Restore Session at Next Start". When you create the .cwl file, are you typing `\colon#m` in TXS or some other application? (I should note that I'm on a Mac.)

Comment: It doesn’t matter where you type it, just be sure it is a normal text file (and it is probably better to not use UTF8). Sorry, the correct route is Options, Configure TeXstudio, Completion tab (as in my answer above).

Comment: Okay, the path is different for Mac, but I found it and selected it. Restarted TXS, but `\colon` doesn't show up in the auto complete list...Ugh.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I've awarded a bounty for your troubles (when it allows me to at least)

Comment: @AlanH Do you have a *Preferences* menu?

Comment: @doncherry Yeah, I believe I found it. Is this it (see update): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113067/how-to-add-custom-commands-to-be-a-part-of-texstudios-autocompletion/113237?noredirect=1#comment249744_113237

Comment: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION

Answer (score 2):

`\colon` is made known to TeXStudio in [`latex-mathsymbols.cwl`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/latex-mathsymbols.cwl), which, as a pre-customized .cwl file, is not directly accessible to the end user, since it is in the compiled program files. (Found through googling [`colon site:http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/`](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=colon%20site:http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/); also see [Where does TeXstudio store the .cwl files for hyperref and xspace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110539/where-does-texstudio-store-the-cwl-files-for-hyperref-and-xspace))

For some reason, all commands from that file are recognized, i.e. suggested as autocompletion and not marked as unknown commands, except for `\colon` and `\lnot`. This seems to be a bug to me. I reported it as bug [#728 \colon and \lnot from latex-mathsymbols.cwl aren’t recognized](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/728/).

Comment: So should I try it with other commands or is there a bug the ability to create *any* sort of custom command?

Comment: @AlanH In the long run, I expect this bug to be fixed in one of the next releases of TXS, so you won’t have to worry about `\colon` anymore. If I understand your question correctly as asking if personal/customized .cwl files are broken in general, the answer is no. I just added `\colon#m` to my personal .cwl file, restarted TXS, and it is recognized just fine.

Comment: so you were able to get `\colon` to show in the autocompletion? If so, then I must have done something wrong... Btw, I don't care so much about `\colon`, I was just trying to follow the example posted by 
Qrrbrbirlbel.

Comment: In my case, I created my personal `cwl` file with the same name as my package `sty` where I defined my personal command. So, only when I load my package TeXstudio suggest the command. The `cwl` file contains only the command (in my case, `\alert{arg}`). Nothing more at the end of line.

Comment: @Sigur Depending on how complex the macro definitions in your personal .sty file are, TXS will automatically recognize the macros. (Not sure if it has to be in the texmf tree as well, this was the case when it worked for me.) However, custom .cwl definitons might be more precise and complete, e.g. in providing an autocomplete entry for a command with and without an optional macro.

Comment: Re bug report: For me, `\colon` is not recognized with SVN 3661 but it is with SVN 3883 (and then even without `latex-mathsymbols.cwl` activated which I can’t remember being in the list of `.cwl` files).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel So TXS 2.5.2 isn’t equals TXS 2.5.2? (I’m on SVN 3661.)

Comment: @doncherry [At their download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%20SVN/) the file contains already `260` but the GUI says 2.5.2.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: With the 'download page' link, you are pointing to the SVN snapshots these are no official releases, but just reflect the state of the project during development. They are for testing and for users, who want to have the cutting edge stuff without compiling themselves. However, the SVN snapshots are less well tested and use on your own risk.

Comment: @doncherry: Yes and no. There is only one official release of 2.5.2. However, there may be multiple SVN snapshots which all carry the same version number (e.g. 2.5.2). Admittedly, naming is not always consistent with the SVN snapshots.