# naming argument and optional-argument for \def, \newcommand and newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments, texstudio, optional-arguments

I know how to create a new command or an environment. I think it will much better if I can specify name of the arguments. For example in `framebox` command and `array` environment below, we know exactly what're the arguments that should be passed.

```
\framebox(xdimen,ydimen)[position]{text}

\begin{array}[pos]{cols}
    content...
\end{array}
```

So far, I've tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\testdef#1#2{#1 #2}

\newcommand{\testcommand}[2]{#1 #2}

\newenvironment{testenv}[2]{#1}{#2}

\begin{document}

\testdef{arg1}{arg2}

\testcommand

\begin{testenv}{1}{2}
content...
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

and you all can see, `\testdef{arg1}{arg2}` just print `arg1` and `arg2` while I need to naming them with, for example, `name` and `value`. It should be

```
\testdef{name}{value}
```

The same goes also for `\testcommand` and `testenv`. So, How can I do that?

> #### Edit
>
> These pictures is taken from TeXstudio.
>
> In picture #1, we see what are arguments for `\framebox`.
>
> [image]
>
> while in picture #2, we just see `\testdef{arg1}{arg2}`.
>
> [image]
>
> Is it behavior of Latex editor? or we can tune it through latex macro?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but I think you are looking for a syntax like `\testdef{arg1=value1, arg2=value2}` in which case you should look at the keyval package (or extended versions such as xkeyval or l3keys)

Comment: I don't really understad what you want. In case of `\def` you are just asking for two usual arguments `{…}{…}`, optionals are a bit more tricky. In `\newcommand` you are doing the same, you need `\newcommand\testcommand[2][]{#1 #2}` or something similar. And in the `\newenvironment` there is a problem, the arguments can only be used in the “opening”; usually in the `\begin` some variables are defined with the arguments, and then in the `\end` they are used. Again, you need `\newenvironment{testenv}[2][]{…}{…}`. Take a look at `xparse`.

Comment: In the _documentation_, something like `\begin{array}[<pos>]{<cols>}` uses `<pos>` and `<cols>` as place-holders to show what is going on, but in the _code_ you still need `#1`, `#2`, _etc._ In TeX parameters have numbers, not names (you can work-around this in LuaTeX, but that I know of this has only been done in ConTeXt and not in LaTeX).

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Your edited question is _just_ about the help prompts added by that editor, it is nothing to do with TeX at all, sorry I can't help as I don't use that editor.

Comment: TeXstudio stores the auto-completion data as a series of `.cwl` files: see _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79643/texstudio-does-not-recognize-colon/85220 for some discussion of altering/adding them. The thing is that this requires knowing what commands to add: are you looking to extend by a 'fixed' set of commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a .cwl file and manually activate in in Options -> completion. See the [FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_does_TXS_know_about_valid_commands.3F) and the [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).