# How can I have TeXstudio recognize my own commands which it already auto-completes?

Tags: texstudio

I have reinstalled TeXstudio and can't seem to find the setting anymore.

I'd like my own commands–which I defined in the preamble–to be recognized by TeXstudio and not highlighted as syntax errors. The thing is, sometimes it already lists the custom commands as possibilities in the auto-completion popup. I think the setting must be hidden somewhere... unless I am mistaken?

Comment: I think your answer is in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79643/texstudio-does-not-recognize-colon

Comment: @R.Schumacher Could you please link the reply or comment which you think includes the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, that your preamble is in a separate file. TXS interprets newcommand definitions and adds these to the list of known commands. Of course, this can only work, if TXS has parsed that part of code.

Therefore, you either need to have the preample file open or activate the option "Editor -> Automatically load included files". Alternatively, you could declare the command via a cwl file and statically enable it in the options.

See also [FAQ: How does TXS know about valid commands](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands).

Comment: "I assume, that your preamble is in a separate file." I could have added that to the op. You assumed right! Thank you, Tim.