# Methods for autocompletion in TexStudio don't work

Tags: packages, texstudio, auto-completion

I've made a `mymacros.sty` file which I would like my LaTeX files to be able to access with commands that I've defined. I've managed to get it to work by putting `\usepackage{mymacros}` in my preamble.

However when I try to autocomplete I can't. I looked at this question:

- [How can I have TeXstudio recognize my own commands which it already auto-completes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251815/how-can-i-have-texstudio-recognize-my-own-commands-which-it-already-auto-complet)
- https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands), which recommends 3 ways of doing this, none of which work for me.

The first it recommends is to have `mymacros.sty` open in the editor. But this doesn't work.

The second is to activate the option `Editor` -> `Automatically load included files` in the `configure TeXstudio` options panel. However while I have an `Editor` tab , there is no such option there.

The third is to using `.cwl` files, however I'm not sure how to go about this. In the completion tab I've noticed that there is a `mymacros.sty` option that has come up, which I ticked but that has had no effect. Do I need to make my own `mymacros.cwl` file? I've tried to look this up but haven't had any luck.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which TeXstudio version are you on? Under the `Configure TeXstudio` options, on the bottom left, there is an option to toggle advanced options. Make sure that is ticked, then check the `Editor` tab again.

Comment: Ah thanks! So I've figured out how to check that box now, but annoyingly its still not working any ideas? My version is 2.12.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't exactly diagnose your problem , but you can create your own `.cwl` file. Hopefully this is an acceptable alternative.

Reference: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION

**1)** The first step is to find the directory where the `.cwl` files are stored.
If you're on Windows, the custom `.cwl` files are stored in `.\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\completion\user` directory. If in doubt, go to `Help`->`Check LaTeX installation` from within TeXstudio and search for `Setting file`. The directory should be printed out for you.

[image: Check latex installation]

**2)** Go to Notepad or any other text editor (TeXstudio works too!). The command syntax for the `.cwl` file is as follows:

`<command>[#classification]`

For a list of classification styles and what they do, refer to the link above, section 4.13.3. For now, try adding just one line to the text file:

`\ThisIsMyCommand#n`

and save it with a file name of your choice. As far as I know, this doesn't have to coincide with your `.sty` name, so let's choose `randomcwl.cwl` as a file name. Ensure that it is `.cwl` file.

[image: notepad]

**3)** Go ahead and place this file into your `.cwl` directory from Step 1.

**4)** Now, if you go to `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Completion`, You'll find the `random.cwl` choice has popped up. Check the box.

[image: random]

**5)** And test it out!

[image: it works!]

Comment: I already tried this and still can't get TeXstudio to autocomplete my macros when using a mymacros.sty file... maybe is a bug in 2.12.8?

Comment: @Saavestro No, I tried on 2.12.8 and it works. More details are probably needed -- if it's going to be exclusively a TXS issue, I would suggest opening an issue on the project Github page instead of on Stackexchange (more appropriate, and more likely to receive proper help)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Since the macros defined in style file didn't appear in auto completion, I copied them in the main file (just temporarily) and it works fine. It's a simple workaround though not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I followed Troy's answer except that I copied the autogenerated .cwl file for my .sty file into the completion/user directory and checked the checkbox next to that file in the configuration as Troy described but autocompletion was still not working.

What solved the issue for me was to remove #S from all commands inside the .cwl file and restart the editor