# TeXstudio chemfig commands marked as unrecognized

Tags: texstudio, chemfig, syntax-highlighting

I included the chemfig package to draw chemical stuff in LaTex.
But the commands aren't recognized by TeXstudio. I even added the package to the autocompletion list in the settings to get recognized in every document but that doesn't help either.

The commands are red like following:

[image: Looks like:]

The file compiles as it should, so everything works except the recognition of the chemfig commands.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TeXnician Obviously how make TeXstudio recognize commands from `chemfig`, though it isn't stated explicitly.

Comment: exactly thank you @Torbjørn T. Have not thought that someone doesn't get what i want to ask with my post...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Short answer:

It's not in the `.cwl` file for some reason, you're gonna have to add it in manually. (I think(!) that's the only alternative. I'm happy to be proven wrong..)

### Long answer:

**The Why:**
Autocompletion and recognition of commands by TeXstudio is controlled by the `.cwl` file, which can be found in your local directory. For Windows, it's in:

```
.\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\completion\user
```

The `.cwl` file autogenerated by TeXstudio looks like this:

[image: cwl file for chemfig]

The commands in the `.cwl` file are in the format: `<command>[#classification]`, so note that there are no `\setatomsep`, `\schemestart`, `\chemfig` etc. commands in here, so that's why they are unrecognized.

Also note that the classification are `#S` which means that they will not appear in the autocompleter tab when typing the command in TeXstudio.

**The How:**

Like I said in the short answer, you're probably gonna have to add the commands in manually if you don't want to see the 'warnings' by TeXstudio about unrecognised commands.

See my other answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534) to find out how. But I have here something you can copy-paste for a quick fix. You just need to add this into your `chemfig.cwl` file and restart your TeXstudio to see its effect. You will need to activate `chemfig.cwl` in the `options -> completion` tab from within TeXstudio as well.

```
\setatomsep{sep dist}#n
\schemestart{your scheme}#n
\chemfig{chem}#n
\+#n
```

*Note:* I chose to use `#n` classification here so you will see it in the autocompleter.

Proof that it works:

[image: proof :)]

**The Hack:**
Of course, there is always the less desirable, but still effective solution of just plain ignoring it. `:p`

You can simply turn off syntax highlighting for a wrong/unrecognized command by TeXstudio, by **right-clicking** on the background colour box to reset it to 'no colour'.

[image: turn off syntax highlighting]

Comment: I have activated chemfig.cwl but still doesn't work. Any ideas?