# custom package and TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, package-writing

I wrote a custom `.sty` file to put all my don't-want-to-carry-around definitions, which provides a new package for me. Now, if I want to use it with TeXstudio (that's what I use for typesetting), TeXstudio doesn't seem to find it (wiggly-underlines it as in "what's that package"). Whenever I want to use a command defined there, TeXstudio can't find it (won't autocomplete (as done with other packages) and highlights it as in "whoa that's a wrong command"), however compiles nicely without errors, as if everything was well-defined.

Why doesn't it recognize the package (and thus won't autocomplete or recognize the commands)?

Comment: I do not think that TeXstudio is reading any style files at all.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner damn

Comment: Autocompletion in TeXstudio is achieved by cwl files. You can just set one up yourself: In the same vein as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364581/117534 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534

Comment: @Marijn You can delete your comment and should, if you now realise it is not helpful.