# How to avoid TeXstudio highlight as wrong some commands?

Tags: texstudio, editors, highlighting

It could be a dummy question, but I'm a little obsessive with the order and organization. I use `TeXstudio` as editor, so when I call the packages, generally the commands associated to them appears as suggestions when I write. However, `TeXstudio` mark as wrong some commands even when I called the package. There are 2 examples for the packages `siunitx` and `makecell`:

Here, the command `\makecell` from `makecell` package appears as wrong and the centimeter option `\cm` from `siunitx` too. It's important to say that I have no problems compilating, it's just an obsession.

[image]

How can I let TeXstudio to recognize this commands (and others that I can't remember) and show them in the siggestions too?

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364581/117534, and read up about cwl's from the texstudio manual.

Comment: They are not marked as wrong, just as not known.