# Commands inside lstnewenvironment not ignored

Tags: listings, environments, texstudio, comments, syntax-highlighting

I am using an lstenvironment to make sure the code is on one page:

```
\lstnewenvironment{mycode}{}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mycode}{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\lstset{style=sharpc}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mycode}{\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{\topskip}}
```

this works but the problem I have when using this is, that the content between `\begin{mycode}` and `\end{mycode}` is not treated like a comment (so commands are not ignored, and spell checking is applied). I would like to have the same behavior like when using `lstlisting` directly.

I tried using the `\comment` command of verbatim and comment packages like this:

```
\newenvironment{mycode}{\comment}{\endcomment}
```

and tried using it inside `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment`
based on some answers I found on related questions (that did not solve my problem).

But it tells me the commands are not known. but when I use `\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}` and same for `\endcomment` it tells me they are already defined. Furthermore I got also errors when I tried using `begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` there.

So does someone know what I am doing wrong or how to get the same behavior like using lstlisting directly?

(Btw. I am using TexStudio 2.12.10 if this is relevant)

**EDIT**
as requested here is my minimal working code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\definecolor{othgray}{RGB}{243, 241, 239}
\usepackage{listings}           % Darstellung von Quellcode
\lstdefinestyle{sharpc}{language=[Sharp]C, basicstyle=\sffamily, keywordstyle={\color{Navy}\bfseries}, commentstyle={\color{DarkGreen}\slshape}, stringstyle={\color{DarkOrange}}, backgroundcolor={\color{othgray}}, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, tabsize=2}

\lstnewenvironment{mycode}[1][]{}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mycode}{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\lstset{style=sharpc}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mycode}{\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{\topskip}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Code}

\begin{mycode}
Excel.Range usedRange = workbook.UsedRange;
Excel.Range firstCell = usedRange[1, 1];
\end{mycode}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**
Seems to be just an editor problem, because it compiles and shows it right when using a nonsense command inside `mycode` without using any comment command. But the editor highlights the command and tells me it is unkown before compiling.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do I understand correctly, that this is an editor issue? So you want your editor not to highlight unknown commands as such and don't apply spellchecking inside of `mycode`? Or is the TeX run failing (without your `\newcommand\comment` stuff)? If the latter, can you please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` including everything necessary to reproduce your issue but nothing more?

Comment: updated with MWE. Tested again, seems to be only a editor problem, because if I put a nonsense command inside `mycode` it does compile and show it, but in the editor it is marked and it tells me the command is not known. When using `lstlisting`the content in it gets green and command are ignored. So yes your first assumption is right

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know my way around TeXstudio and can't really help you with that (but chances are that in the next hours there is someone who can). You should reword your question though to make it clear that it is only about the syntax highlighting of TeXstudio in this case.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you just need a [custom `.cwl` file](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) with `\begin{mycode}#V` in it. If you don't know how to use `.cwl` files, see a [related answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534).

Comment: You can also add the environment as a custom environment in the _preferences_ → _own highlighting_ (_Eigene Hervorhebung_ in my german version). However it’ll still try to spell check that. Seems like the disabled spellcheck for `{verbatim}` is hard coded and not generally applied to all verbatim like environments.

Comment: @Tobi spellcheck for verbatim environments is controlled by cwl as well. The custom environment setting is only for syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Troy: Ah. Thanks for the information. Maybe you like to make an answer and explain how to write the CWL, where to save it and how to use/activate it in TeXstudio.

Comment: @Alex Are there any updates here? Can you confirm whether I've understood your question correctly, or not? And whether my suggestion works for you, or not?

Comment: @Troy Thanks, yes you understood my question correctly and you provided me the right solution. I created a `.cwl` file with `\begin{mycode}#V` in it and added it in settings under completion. While @Tobi 's Answer also worked for disabling spell checking (and coloring it green like in lstlisting) your solution also disabled highlighting of latex commands and this way is even better than lstlisting which does this not. @Troy do you want to make an answer that I can accept or should I do this myself?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for confirming, I was reluctant to write up an answer if I misunderstood your question. :) I'll write one up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax highlighting in TeXstudio is controlled by [.cwl files](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).
With the creation of a new (verbatim) environment called `mycode`, the way to let TXS know about this is to do so with a user-created `.cwl` file (it's just a text file).

Put this inside your cwl file:

```
\begin{mycode}#V
\end{mycode}
```

where the `#V` classifier declares a verbatim-like environment (thus all syntax checking turned off, just like in `\lstlisting`).

For info on how to use `.cwl` files, see my [previous answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534) on the topic.