# Texstudio suggestions from inside new figure command

Tags: floats, environments, texstudio, labels

because of some ugly corporate design I needed to create the following figure environment/design with the caption on the right side.

Problem is, that I don't get suggestions from the label inside the

```
\figthree{sample.jpg}{caption}{fig:label}
```

command.

```
\newcommand{\figthree}[3]{\begin{figure}
[!h]%\makebox[131.8mm+4.32cm][l]{
                \raggedright
\begin{minipage}[t]{131.8mm}%               \input{#1}  
            \vspace*{0pt}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
        \end{minipage}
%   \hspace*{2mm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{42mm}
            \vspace{-\ht\strutbox}%
            \captionof{figure}{#2}\label{#3}%
        \end{minipage}%}
\end{figure}}
```

Comment: TeXStudio's parser is unlikely to see the label there really, because it would need to parse the (really weird) `\figthree` command and understand that its third argument is a label. A hack that _could_ work is to add `\iffalse\label{fig:label}\fi`. It wouldn't be seen by TeX but TeXStudio might see it...

Comment: You can write a cwl file for your command `\figthree`. Maybe something like `\figthree{imagefile}{caption%text}{label}#l` should work.

Comment: @Troy doesn't that just make an interface for `\figthree`? The OP is looking for a solution that adds the label to the list of known label keys you get when you write `\ref`

Comment: @daleif Yes, true, but it *also* adds the third argument passed to `\figthree` to the list of labels recognized by TXS. That's the point of the `#l` classifier. Hence, the label will be presented as an option for autocompletion when using `\ref`.

Comment: @Troy ahh, nice

Comment: @Troy Thank you very much!!!!  works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `.cwl` file for your command `\figthree` and use the special argument name `label` with the classifier `#l` so that TXS recognize the third argument as a label. 
See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534) if you are unsure how to write a `.cwl` file.

```
\figthree{imagefile}{caption%text}{label}#l
```

Proof that it works:

[image: pic]