# LaTeX Grammar and Nesting Rule

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, nesting, parsing, arguments

Is there any grammar and rule describing the allowed nestings and combinations and the allowed format of the arguments in LaTeX? E.g.

```
\section{\verb|mySec|}

\section{\begin{huge}mySec\end{huge}}

\section{\section{mySec}}
```

is invalid LaTeX code.
Or something that astonished me was

```
\begin{section}{mySec}
bla bla
\end{section}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics{image.png}
\begin{caption}{myCaption}
bla bla
\end{caption}
\end{figure}
```

I never saw section and caption declared like this but it is valid.
I am working on a semi LaTeX parser and such a rule would help me.

Comment: A LaTeX parser can (and will) be quite tricky to build. Take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446029/134574) of mine. The use case is different, but the principle still applies. `\begin{section}{mySec}
bla bla
\end{section}` because the `\begin` part effectively does `\section{mySec}` and the `\end` part does `\relax`, which is nothing. This syntax can cause some unexpected behavior in the document though, so it _really_ shouldn't be used. The same goes for the `\begin{caption}{myCaption}`.

Answer (score 5):

`\verb` has a non-grammatical constraint that it can not be used in the argument of any command so

```
\section{\verb|mySec|}
```

is a syntax error.

---

```
\section{\begin{huge}mySec\end{huge}}
```

is not a syntax error and has well defined output but it is really poor style, there should be no formatting in the argument of `\section` the whole point of latex is that styling for things like section heads is in class setup not inline in the document. the particular markup `\begin{huge}mySec\end{huge}` is poor even if not in a section heading as it specifies huge text on a normal baseline so uneven linespacing. But again this is a matter of poor user style not a grammar error that a parser can pick up.

---

```
 \section{\section{mySec}}
```

there is no specific rule preventing this but it is nonsensical input that gives some more or less accidental low level error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 5.
```

---

```
\begin{section}{mySec}
bla bla
\end{section}
```

is valid, if unusual, markup equivalent by design to

```
{\section{mysec} bla bla }
```

---

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics{image.png}
\begin{caption}{myCaption}
bla bla
\end{caption}
\end{figure}
```

This is also valid but unusual markup but in this case probably not what the author intended. It is equivalent to

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics{image.png}
{\caption{myCaption}
bla bla
}
\end{figure}
```

---

A classic test for latex parsers would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}
\newcommand\biggskip{\par\vspace{5pt}}
\begin{document}


\let ~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
 PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A @@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PA YY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbiggskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PA XX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71  72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71  72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@  lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i.  i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx  ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW  qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jstop
```