# Printing labels into file to support editor

Tags: macros, ide

I am using the following command to define a custom counter for different things I refer later in the document.

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\customcounter}[2]{%
    \newcounter{#1} \setcounter{#1}{0} \crefname{#1}{#2}{#2s}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\noindent%
        \refstepcounter{#1}\textbf{#2\arabic{#1}}\label{##1}\\%
        \makeatletter
    }
}
\customcounter{goal}{G}
\customcounter{functionalrequirement}{FR}
```

When referencing things, I normally get hints from my editor (visual studio code with tex workshop or TexStudio). But when using these labels defined this way, it does not pick up the labels.

I had two solutions to this:

1. Move the labels out of the command and write them directly behind it ( so \goal{g:reach-himalaya} would become \goal\label{g:reach-himalaya}). But this did not work, as the label now pointed to the last section instead of my goal.
2. Create a .tex file, where i print all the labels I generate again. This file is then included with \input inside a false if block. This way, the IDE picks up the labels, but the generation still works. I couldn't get this to work, as it did not let me correctly print the commands into the file

Now my question is: How could I correctly implement any of these solutions? I think that **1** is a bit cleaner code-wise and less of a workaround. On the other hand solution **2** is also interesting, as it makes the usage of the commands easier.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: A manual way to get TXS to recognize the labels is to just create a `.cwl` entry for each of your new 'counters'. For example, `\goal{label}#l` if you have `\customcounter{goal}{G}`. Read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534) and the TeXstudio user manual if you need an intro to cwl.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But as you sad it would be manual and involve a lot of work to set that up, and not be portable to other editors. Then I would probably be better off to just write a regex that searches for my command, and writes my fake input file

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, that is very similar to the first proposed solution. I pulled the \label part out of the command definition.
the code now looks like this:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\customcounter}[2]{%
    \newcounter{#1} \setcounter{#1}{0} \crefname{#1}{#2}{#2s} \crefformat{#1}{#2##2##1##3}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\noindent%
        \refstepcounter{#1}\textbf{#2\arabic{#1}}##1\\%
    }
}
\customcounter{goal}{G}
```

and can be used with:

```
\goal{\label{g:reach-himalaya}}
```