# \autoref with subfiles in TexStudio

Tags: hyperref, texstudio, subfiles

I am using TexStudio with the `subfiles` package to split my project into smaller pieces, with the advantage that I can compile a subfile indepentent of the main stuff.
Now using the `\autoref` command of the `hyperref` package I would like to have auto completion for the labels when working in a subfile, but TexStudio does not give me a list of labels in the other documents.

One way out that I know is to use a `%!TEX root = main.tex` at the beginning of a subfile, but then maint.tex will always be executed, making the `subfiles` package useless.

Any ideas how to use `\autoref` across different subfiles?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/247#issue-343312506

Comment: I am 50% sure about this, but I think referencing files in your structure is somewhat similar to using your own commands, i.e. if you like TeXstudio to recognize your files, there is an option you can check. More here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251815/how-can-i-have-texstudio-recognize-my-own-commands-which-it-already-auto-complet

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using subfiles you could use the \include statement 
This way you'll compile only the modified files. That should allow you to use
`%!TEX root = main.tex`

Here some useful links:

[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents

Comment: If I get the \include statement right, I would have to use \includeonly to specify the subfile I want to work with. This would mean I have to change main.tex everytime I start working on another subfile. In particular, since I am using Git, the main.tex file would be seen as edited, even if I did not change anything substantial. All of this is not too bad, but still unconvenient...

Comment: When you use the \include only statement it will use old .aux files for the other chapters. Thus you should initially process the file without \includeonly so that all chapters are processed and usable aux files are generated for each chapter.

Comment: @MarvinDippell when you are working mainly on a certain part, you could use `\includeonly` and not change its arguments, even when you do changes on other subfiles of the document. If you are not making major changes, why bother running that subfiles. Just run the subfiles that might start causing problems because of the changes. Most of the times, those will be major changes and you will inevitably choose to activate that specific file in the `\includeonly` argument. This is just what I do.