# Wrapfigure unrecognized environment

Tags: errors, texstudio, tikz-styles, wrapfigure

TeXstudio has highlighted this for some time. same problem indicates it in the commands:

```
\tikzmarknode{}, \eqdescbox, \dimexpr
```

I have no problems in compiling the pdf file, I only see these things highlighted. I did an update of TexLive the other day but I still have this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe} 

\newcommand*{\Fra}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\ccdot}{\,\mathrm{\!\cdot\!}}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{3.0cm}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{particella1}
    \label{fig:partstab}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to retag the question: as far as I understand, this has nothing to do with TeX errors but rather with the editor TeXStudio.

Comment: If you don't give the code in text and compileable format, few people will answer you: no one wants to copy the text from an image manually!

Comment: @AndréC it is not a question of text or compilation. I have no problem compiling the file. I do not understand why some commands see them this way

Comment: The editor has no way of knowing all commands and environments there is in LaTeX, so it only provides a special interface for a subset of these. It is probably a bit confusing for the user when the editor says something like that, not knowing that the user has not made any mistake.

Comment: @daleif I thought about this possibility. is defined as a syntax error. I do not understand where I can correct this the error

Comment: @Antonio Can you compile the file and get what you want? If you can get what you want, this is only a problem of your editor.

Comment: You might want to give a look at the [TeXStudio documentation](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), sections 1.4, 1.5 and 4.13.  Here on the site there are similar questions, like [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47493/82917), [TeXStudio does not recognize `\colon`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79643/82917).

Comment: @campa I did a verification, even forcing the upload to continue giving this error. I disabled syntax checking.

You can also switch off syntax checking at Configure ... -> Editor -> Inline Checking -> Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me this way:

- create a new .txt file
- open the .txt file with Notepad++ (free txt program)
- In the opened file, Insert:

```
# wrapfig package
# Matthew Bertucci 8/31/2021 for v3.6 

# added the next 2 lines:
\begin{wrapfigure}%\    %<content...%>%\
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfig}{position}{width}
\begin{wrapfig}[lineheight]{position}[overhang%l]{width}
\end{wrapfig}
\begin{wraptable}{position}{width}#*
\begin{wraptable}[lineheight]{position}[overhang%l]{width}#*
\end{wraptable}#*
\begin{wrapfloat}{floatname}{position}{width}#*
\end{wrapfloat}#*
\wrapoverhang#*
```

- Credit: The code is copied from (added the first 2 lines):
  https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/wrapfig.cwl
- Saving the file:

  - browse to: C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\completion\user
  - giving file name: wrapfig.cwl
  - Save as type: All types(*.*)
- loading the .cwl file:

  - in TeXstudio, select: options > Configure TeXstudio
  - from list in left side, select: Completion
  - from list in right side, tick the box beside wrapfig.cwl
- after clicking 'ok' it starts loading the file, the red mark will disappear and there no longer 'unrecognized environment'.

They are some notes I found here and there and gathered it together in one place. Hope it helps.