# \begin{algorithm} unrecognized

Tags: algorithm2e

I have used these two packages for creating algorithm

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

But `\begin{algorithm}` shows as unrecognized command. Even `\For`, `\While` are shown as unrecognized. I don't understand. I'm using TexStudio as editor.
Here is a sample code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Retiming Algorithm to compute Shortest Path}
 Set count = 1 \linebreak
\While{count $\le$ V}{
Set W(U,V) = $\infty$ \linebreak
Set D(U,V) = -1 \linebreak
 count $\gets$ count + 1 
}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

If I run above code, I get no errors but \While, \begin{algorithm} are coming as unrecognized commands. I'm not good at LaTeX. I've used google as source to write this.

Comment: TeXStudio is irrelevant in this context (editors usually are). Please provide a full minimal example, i.e., something that we can copy'n'paste to our own systems without having to add anything. You do not provide any information about which document class your are using.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: No problems here. Which LaTeX installation are you using?

Comment: I'm using TexStudio. even i've no errors but that shows as unrecognized command in the editor.

Comment: What do you mean by *unrecognized in the editor*? No editor knows about all possible macro names.

Answer (score 3):

To recognise the commands from a package, TeXStudio needs a corresponding file with the extension `.cwl`. For some of the most common packages, the `cwl` files are provided as standard, and they can be activated as discussed in [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47493/2417).

I don't think `cwl` files are provided for `algorithm2e` or `algorithmicx`, but section 1.5 of the [TeXStudio User Manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html) explains how to create your own.

Comment: I had checked the cwl files required but it is still shown as unrecognized.

Comment: Those were probably auto generated by TeXStudio so checking them won't make a difference. You can open them and see.