# TeXStudio doesn't recognize \big( or \big[

Tags: texstudio

When I use `\big(` or `\big[` in math mode I get a message unrecognized command, but I have no error and it gives me the desired result. However, the command `\big|` works fine. When I use the same commands with space between `\big` and `(` or `[` there is no problem. This has happened the last few days, when I upgraded TexStudio to 2.12.8 version.

I would like that TeXStudio recognize `\big(`, `\big[`, `\bigg(`,... without space. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an answer but usually `\bigl(...\bigr)` is better, i.e. you should include an `l` or `r` to indicate an opening or closing fence. Maybe that can help TeXstudio. Anyway this should only be a message by your editor and not a TeX warning or error. So you can safely ignore it.

Comment: It doesn't work with `l` or `r`. Suddenly it recognize `\big(` but not `\big)` or `\bigg(`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47493/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79643/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185086/35864 and in particular https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands

Comment: Thank you! I have already read them but I don't know how to create .cwl. Anyway, I will try again.

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to make your own cwl for this. Go to `Configure TeXstudio -> Completion`: Is `latex-document.cwl` checked? If not, try to check it and see if it helps. (It should: the `\big` commands are defined in it.)

Comment: `latex-document.cwl` is checked but not fix it

Comment: @fotis81 Ok, confirmed. Will try to look into it.

Answer (score 7):

### Fixed for TXS ≥ 2.12.9 (git [b1157fa](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/commit/b1157fa233e469f28059d338d9f3c817c33130e5))

The issue has been fixed in the developmental snapshot, which can be downloaded from

- Windows: https://bintray.com/sunderme/texstudio/texstudio-win/2.12.9-201806161911-git_b1157fa#files
- MacOS: https://bintray.com/sunderme/texstudio/texstudio-osx/2.12.9-201806161913-git_b1157fa#files

Future released (official) versions from `2.12.10` onwards will not need the below workaround.

---

### Workaround (TXS ≤ version 2.12.8)

> **Note:** As suggested in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436648/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-big-or-big/436703?noredirect=1#comment1095578_436703), `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` etc. are recommended instead. These are defined in `latex-mathsymbols.cwl`, so they may require a similar fix.
>
> There's no elegant way about it now, if the other commands from `latex-document.cwl` are affected from disabling it, you can copy-paste its entire contents from the [source code](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/latex-document.cwl) and proceed similarly with `tempfix.cwl` for now.

Seems to be a <s>mis-categorization</s> bug in the implementation of the classification format of commands in `latex-document.cwl` and `latex-mathsymbols.cwl`. You can't edit this directly because it is compiled into the executable. I'll offer an alternative for now:

1. Create a new `tempfix.cwl` file using notepad or some other text editor.
2. Go to the [project page](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/tree/master/completion) and copy the contents of `latex-document.cwl` and `latex-mathsymbols.cwl` into `tempfix.cwl`.
3. Then replace the relevant `\big(`, `\bigl(` etc. commands with: (Essentially remove the `K` and `M` classification from `#mK` or `#mM`.)

   ```
   \Big(%|\Big)#m
   \Big[%|\Big]#m
   \Big|%|\Big|#m
   \big(%|\big)#m
   \big[%|\big]#m
   \big|%|\big|#m
   \Bigg(%|\Bigg)#m
   \Bigg[%|\Bigg]#m
   \Bigg|%|\Bigg|#m
   \bigg(%|\bigg)#m
   \bigg[%|\bigg]#m
   \bigg|%|\bigg|#m

   \Bigl(%|\Bigr)#m
   \Bigl[%|\Bigr]#m
   \Bigl|%|\Bigr|#m
   \bigl(%|\bigr)#m
   \bigl[%|\bigr]#m
   \bigl|%|\bigr|#m
   \Biggl(%|\Biggr)#m
   \Biggl[%|\Biggr]#m
   \Biggl|%|\Biggr|#m
   \biggl(%|\biggr)#m
   \biggl[%|\biggr]#m
   \biggl|%|\biggr|#m
   \Bigr#m
   \bigr#m
   \Biggr#m
   \biggr#m
   ```
4. Place `tempfix.cwl` in the `./config/completion/user/` folder (see [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#where-are-the-settings-stored) if you're unsure where this is), and restart TeXstudio.
   Check the `testfix.cwl` in `Configure TeXstudio -> Completion`, and uncheck `latex-document.cwl`, `latex-mathsymbols.cwl`.

[image: tempfix]

Close the options dialog, then from the top bar, `Idefix -> Refresh structure` if necessary to 'refresh' the commands recognition.

This should be fixed in the next release (> TXS version `2.12.8`).

**Test file:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$
\Big(x+y\Big)
\Big[x+y\Big]
\Big|x+y\Big|
\big(x+y\big)
\big[x+y\big]
\big|x+y\big|
\Bigg(x+y\Bigg)
\Bigg[x+y\Bigg]
\Bigg|x+y\Bigg|
\bigg(x+y\bigg)
\bigg[x+y\bigg]
\bigg|x+y\bigg|
\Bigl(x+y\Bigr)
\Bigl[x+y\Bigr]
\Bigl|x+y\Bigr|
\bigl(x+y\bigr)
\bigl[x+y\bigr]
\bigl|x+y\bigr|
\Biggl(x+y\Biggr)
\Biggl[x+y\Biggr]
\Biggl|x+y\Biggr|
\biggl(x+y\biggr)
\biggl[x+y\biggr]
\biggl|x+y\biggr|
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but it should be `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` (the same for `[` and `]`) nontheless.

Comment: It works, but now other commands have the same problem because `latex-document.cwl` is un-checked. Anyway, Ι understand how the whole thing works. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: @egreg Indeed. Thanks, will include the fix later. No time to do it in detail now, but I'll add a note in my answer for now.

Comment: I downloaded this file
https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/latex-document.cwl
and I changed specific commands with yours
e.g. `\big(%|\big)#mM` --> `\big(%|\big)#m`.
I think it was fixed. The strange is that `\big|` is fine, but `\big(` or `\big[` had problem. Anyway, which I can find examples for creating files .cwl?

Comment: @fotis81 The [user manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) describes the cwl syntax. For examples, just browse [the source code](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/tree/master/completion) or search this site for `[texstudio] cwl` for example. Anyway, I think it's a bug with the `M` and `K` formats, so what I have above is a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: Τhank you for your help!

Comment: @fotis81 If you can, give the developmental snapshot a go (see updated answer). The bug has been fixed. (Also, do take the advice of the other users and use `\bigl(...\bigr)` instead of `\big(..\big)`.)