# How do I get TeXStudio to stop fixing \ch to \chapter?

Tags: texstudio

I use TeXStudio when writing body text. One nice feature is it will autocomplete a lot of commands for you. The problem I'm having is that if I type `\ch{` it 'fixes' this to `\chapter{`. Is there any way to turn this off, or add `\ch` to it above `\chapter`?

Comment: Go to options->configure Texstudip than completion buttun desable Auto replace latex commands

Comment: Check to make sure that `\ch` is in a `.cwl` that is being loaded by TeXstudio. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47529/42880) and section 4.13 of the [TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: If your are referring to `\ch` from `chemformula` you might be interested in my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263504

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Finally got around to setting this up, can you make it an answer?

Comment: @Canageek this would be a duplicate then. Just accept Mr. Zentz answer as the first sentence was exactly what helped you. Or you close your post ad a dupe with reference to the post I linked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure that `\ch` is in a `.cwl` that is being loaded by TeXstudio. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-some-commands/47529#47529) to [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-some-commands/47529) and section 4.13 of the [TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: I finally set down and double checked this, and yes, the entire `chemmacros` family is loaded in TeXStudio.